# Using geometry nodes to make 3 layer corrugated cardboard (which is easily animatable!)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm fairly new to Blender (but with a decent amount of experience of other CG software).  So far, I'm absolutely loving it!

I'm trying my first real project in Blender, making an animation using corrugated cardboard, and I've come to the realisation that rather than just using textures, I'm going to need 3 layers of geometry (two flat cardboard ones on either side, and the wiggly-padding bit in the middle).

I also need to keep it reasonably simple, as there is a lot of animation and folding involved.  So what I'd like is to animate simple geometry (the "outer layer" of cardboard) then have the inner wiggly bit and other flat bit of cardboard filled in automatically using geometry nodes.

I've got the first bit sorted in geometry nodes, 2 layers that work off the base layer and distribute away from the face normals.

I've tried to use a material and displacement on the middle layer to create the wiggly bumps.  It's okaaaay, and at a push it's probably usable with a bit of tweaking (if we ignore how massively dense the middle layer will have to be) - but I was wondering if there was any way to create this effect with geometry nodes?

[image]

(this is with the displacement driving the middle layer)

I can get something working in geometry nodes using sin and setting the Z position based on the X position, but this obviously won't take into account the angle of the geometry or the animation as it bends and moves.

Is there something (probably way above my pay-grade!) that I could do using sin but based on the face normals and calculating the distance to the next vertex in a certain direction based on those normal values?  Or something else I haven't thought about?

Any help gratefully received at this point!!

### Cheers

Comment: So I've got it working (a bit).  It relies on UV data, which is not exactly what I was after, but it does take care of the wrinkly geom inside geometry nodes, which was the main thing.  I'm commenting in case anyone else stumbles across this and I can save them an hour of reading manuals and bashing buttons!

Basically I used a "Named Attribute" node which is able to pull in UV co-ordinates, and then I split the co-ordinate value using a Separate XYZ node and used the Y value to drive the sine function to create the waves. Then I just offset the points by that value along their normal.